# NinePatchDrawable causes ClassCastException in Android Studio 0.3.6

Tags: java, android, android-studio, classcastexception, nine-patch

**Situation:**

NinePatchDrawable in custom view causing `java.lang.ClassCastException` in the Android Studio 0.3.6 *XML Layout Editor*.

The occurring error is straightforward however the reason is not. Worth noting is that the error arose and was not originally there (a few weeks ago).

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable`

**Code and Resources:**

This code line is causing the issue:

`mTestImage = (NinePatchDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_test);`

This is the error log:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable
    at com.swiftdroid.colorbar.ColorBar.init(ColorBar.java:88)
    at com.swiftdroid.colorbar.ColorBar.<init>(ColorBar.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:98)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:157)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:154)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:542)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:535)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:934)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:535)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:577)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7$2.compute(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:501)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7$2.compute(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:945)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:494)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:297)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

This is the NinePatchDrawable:

[Test Image](http://oi40.tinypic.com/2ewmz9d.jpg) (upscaled)

[Project Structure](http://oi44.tinypic.com/f3hy4p.jpg) (contains actual names however the issue and resource layout are the same)

Still can't post images until 2 more rep is acquired :(

**Question:**

Can anybody reproduce this? Does anybody have a similar issue?

*Currently occurs in Android Studio 0.3.6 - ADT an Build Tools 19 - SDK 22.3 - Android 4.4*

Comment: apparently your drawable is a statelistdrawable. it is possible that the compiler is lost somewhere. in which case, clean/build cycle should solve this.

Comment: Can we assume that there is no `img_test.xml` in `res/drawable` that looks somehow like [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) - you actually have a `img_test.9.png`?

Comment: Currently the image resides in a library package and the only resource is `img_test.9.png`. Furthermore this is not an issue in the actual android application, only in the layout editor. Cleaning/rebuilding/restarting has no effect either :(